# Modify Equation of sphere intersection

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, 3d, intersection-theory, spheres

I got to know how to modify formula for radius of circle formed after intersection of two spheres when centres of both spheres where at origin or at x axis to centres at any arbitary positions $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ from [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501846/all-intersection-points-of-two-spheres-having-arbitary-centres).

[image: sphere intersection]

I was able to understand these:
$$h^2 = \frac{4 d^ 2 r1^2 - (d^2 - r2^2 + r1^2)^2}{ 4 d^2}$$

where

$$d^2=(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2+(z2-z1)^2$$

The [equation of circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html) after intersection of spheres with centres at $(0,0,0)$ and $(d,0,0)$ is $$x=\frac{d^2-r1^2+r2^2}{2d}$$  and parallel to $yz$ plane: $$y^2+z^2=\frac{4 d^2 r2^2-(d^2-r1^2+r2^2)^2}{4 d^2}$$

How could i modify this equation when centres of spheres are at $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.?

Comment: The general equations can be obtained by rotating/translating the coordinates. The rotation matrix is computed from the vector $P_1P_2$ and an arbitrary one, using the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process. But I bet you will be disappointed as you will end-up with the implicit equation of a plane and that of a sphere. What is your purpose ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust i have to code in c++ **given two arbitary centres of spheres and their radii print a general equation of thier intersection**. since my core subjects are progamming related i have little knowledge of mathmatics. i will be highly grateful if you will help me.

Comment: Do you have to format the equations ?? This is an unusual project.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No format, any format will help.....if you have something that will be of any help please provide.

Comment: Start by printing the reduced equations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what is a reduced equation? and how can we calculate?

Comment: Start by printing *any* equation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Okay i have taken out centre coordinates of the circle ,radius of the circle and line equation (vector) of the line connecting the two centres. With these can i calculate the equation of circle.??